# Openvpn leading -- error parse from txt username and password

Tags: bash, ubuntu, openvpn

Hello I'm trying to access openvpn from ubuntu command line by trying to enter the sudo password and the username and password for openvpn altogether based on those answers:

sudo password from command line:

[Use sudo with password as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955298/use-sudo-with-password-as-parameter)

openvpn username and password from command line:

[linux: passing username and password in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869427/linux-passing-username-and-password-in-command-line)

This is the command I'm entering:

```js
echo 12345 | sudo -S openvpn <openvpnpath> --auth-user-pass pass.txt
```

Where inside pass.txt I have:

a@gmail.com

56789

But I'm getting the following error:

Options error: I'm trying to parse "/etc/openvpn..." as an --option parameter but I don't see a leading '--'
Use --help for more information.

Am I missing something? Thnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `--config`? Just:

```
echo 12345 | sudo -S openvpn --config /path/to/config.file --auth-user-pass pass.txt
```

Comment: I'm trying to use a specific file if I remove it I won't be able to do it. That's why I must specify the path

Answer (score 0):

openvpn --config openvpn.ovpn.3
[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can add your credentials, to configuration file

1. Edit your `.ovpn` file

   > `vi <filename>.ovpn`
2. replace `auth-user-pass` to `auth-user-pass < credentials_file.txt >`

   > `auth-user-pass < credentials_file.txt >`

```
    client
    dev tun
    proto udp
    ; Cert
    ns-cert-type server
    cipher BF-CBC
    ;Host
    resolv-retry infinite
    ;auth
    auth-user-pass "C:\\Program\\OpenVPN\\config\\selogin.txt"

    remote xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    persist-key
    persist-tun
    nobind
    comp-lzo
    verb 2
    <ca>
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    xxxx
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    </ca>
```

3. connect to vpn

   > `sudo openvpn <openvpnpath>`